# Firebird ODBC Connection from server 2008 64 bit To server 2003 32 bit which has the database

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5, firebird-embedded, firebird1.5

I have a Quantum database that is using Firebird connection on a windows 2003 32 bit. I am trying to connect to the server through ODBC from a server 2008 R2 64 bit but it tells me "Failed to open database xxx connection" every time I click on test connection. I installed the latest 32 bit and 64 bit driver on the 2008 server and upgraded the Firebird diver on the 2003 server to the latest 32 bit driver. What am I missing? I am trying to connect to the database server so I can migrate the database to SQL.

Comment: Your tags don't match the body of your question...

Comment: thanks. I changed the tags.

Comment: Is there a firewall in the way?

Comment: No firewall. Only Symantec endpoint protection on the 2008 server.

Comment: Check if this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569933/access-a-32-bit-firebird-database-from-a-64-bit-app-via-odbc) helps you.

Comment: No o already have installed both drivers on the server.